# Change in commit is gone

Tags: git, gitlab

I encountered a weird problem with git. The change of a commit is **gone**. Although I can still view this commit in the history, the latest code doesn't include the changes of the commit.

This commit does have some specialty. It had a future commit timestamp (a year later). This was caused by mistake. My environment had been changed to a future time for testing, but I forgot to `ntpdate` the time back before I committed and pushed to our gitlab server.

After that commit, there are two more commits by others. The procedure:

- *the special commit with a future timestamp*
- one more commit
- another commit (changes are gone here)

Does anyone know why this happened and how I can get the changes of this commit back?

Comment: Have you tried amending the commit to change the date?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, I tried. It didn't help on getting the changes back. There does have a solution that using `git cherry-pick` to include that commit again, and amend the date. That's what I do right now. Just want to know why this is happening (changes are gone) and how to avoid in future.

Comment: Would it be possible that someone force-pushed to the GitLab server?